# Can we pass errors as props from catch block in reactJS and show them in new reusable component where props will resemble different errors

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-hooks

Below method isn't working. I also tried using useHistory but how to pass props using useHistory , Redirect method also not working

For example

```
Inside Functional Component{



 instance.get(url).catch((error)=>{

 
        if(error.response){

          if(error.response.status===404){
                  
                   <ErrorComponent err={error.response.status}/>
                   console.log("Page Not Found");
               }
          if(error.response.status===400){
                
               <ErrorComponent err={error.response.status}/>
               console.log("Bad Request")
           }
      }
  }
}
```

Comment: Instead of rendering a component this way, it is advised to write to a state, let's say for simplicity, you can write to your additional `state = { error : { msg : "error message" }}`. This will ensure that your logic ( calling backend and doing calculations ) are different from the ones that are rendering the components

Comment: if you are good with react, you can use redux state to easily overcome this problem by making appropriate slices of the reducer and rendering them accordingly.